# Hide public posts on Facebook profile

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-timeline, facebook-privacy, facebook-profile

I have certain posts that I want to be public, i.e. visible to everyone who has a link to it, shareable and re-postable, but I still would like to hide the post from the list of posts visible on my timeline to the public.

In other words, I want to curate my public profile view independently of the privacy settings of the individual posts.

Does Facebook support that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** Make a post set to public then:

- Click the Activity Log button near the top of your timeline
- Click the pencil button next to whatever update you just made and select **"Hidden from Timeline"**

Comment: Great, thanks. How about „Hidden from the timeline for everyone but friends“?…

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is possible. You could potentially set the privacy settings to "Only friends can see" but then it wouldn't be a public post :( If you are very specifically trying to share a message that only your friends can see on your timeline but the public can also view it. Perhaps post it on a different site e.g https://pastebin.com/ and link to it in a private (only friends) post on facebook? And that share that link with whoever you want to see the content but isn't on your friends list?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I’ll stick with “not possible”